# Clonar formularios de manera independiente

Tags: javascript

Tengo un formulario de los cuales algunos campos se pueden clonar en funcion de las necesidades del usuario.

He utilizado un script de java que me permite hacerlo, pero no he sabido separa todas las variables para que funcionen independiente.

Cuando clono no hay problema,el valor de las variables "i" y "a" se incrementan de manera independiente, pero cuando borro alguno de los div clonados interactuan del alguna manera.

Si borro algun div de las variables "i" cuando añado otro de las variables "a" el valor de "a" se ha visto afectado por el borrado de los div de "i".

He intentado variar el código sin exito, me es muy complicado entender la lógica del código en java script.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var i=1;
        $('#addcli').click(function(){
            i++;
            $('#dynamic_fieldcon').append('<tr id="rowcli'+i+'"><td><div class="col-xs-3"><label for="ex1">Contacto</label><input class="form-control" name="nombreconcli[]" id="nombreconcli_'+i+'" type="text"></div><div class="col-xs-3"><label for="ex2">Teléfono</label><input class="form-control" name="telefonoconcli[]" id="telefonoconcli_'+i+'" type="text"></div><div class="col-xs-5"><label for="ex3">Mail</label><input class="form-control" name="mailconcli[]" id="mailconcli_'+i+'" type="text"></div><a href="#" name="removecli" id="cli'+i+'" id="addcli" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">-</a></td></tr>');

        });


        $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
            i--;
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
            $('#rowcli'+button_id+'').remove();
        });
    });
    </script>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var a=1;
        $('#addpro').click(function(){
            a++;
            $('#dynamic_fieldconpro').append('<tr id="rowpro'+a+'"><td><div class="col-xs-3"><label for="ex1">Contacto</label><input class="form-control" name="nombreconpro[]" id="nombreconpro_'+a+'" type="text"></div><div class="col-xs-3"><label for="ex2">Teléfono</label><input class="form-control" name="telefonoconpro[]" id="telefonoconpro_'+a+'" type="text"></div><div class="col-xs-5"><label for="ex3">Mail</label><input class="form-control" name="mailconpro[]" id="mailconpro_'+a+'" type="text"></div><a href="#" name="removepro" id="pro'+a+'"  class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">-</a></td></tr>');

        });


        $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
            a--;
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
            $('#rowpro'+button_id+'').remove();
        }); 
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: No tienes porque decrementar las variables cuando borras.  Intenta remover `i--` y `a--`

Comment: tienes dos declaraciones de id en `removecli`

Comment: No decrementes déjale el id incrementado y si borran que borren toda la posición sin decrementar javascript no es tan restrictivo con eso

Answer (score 0):

que es lo que usas para clonar tu formulario??

tengo un problema similar pero no entiendo muy bien tu código, yo estaba clonando con cloneNode, pero no los trabaja de manera independiente, pero si los borra me parece que de manera correcta, este es mi código

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.input-group').parent().on('click', '.remove-field',function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
});
```

es muy similar pero espero que las diferencias te ayuden